# Apklib type of library

Tags: android, gradle, apklib

I use Android Studio with gradle and i need to add library,that has apklib type. How i can convert it to aar type?
Because, when i run my program - it fails.

This is my dependency for my library:

```
compile 'com.squareup:android-times-square:1.0.3'
```

Comment: This might help: 
http://gmariotti.blogspot.hu/2013/06/quick-tips-convert-to-new-gradle-based.html